# Django. Как вывести в шаблон html только те поля FileField, которые хранят файл?

Tags: python, django

Есть модель с 14ю полями **FileField** (все поля blank=True). Файлы через эти поля будут переданы только через админку.

models.py
(... - использовал для сокращения модели)

```
from django.db import models

class Project(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text="Ориентир (локация)", verbose_name="Где находится")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True, help_text="Ссылка страницы объекта (генерируется автоматически)", verbose_name="Ссылка на страницу")
    ready = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="Дом сдан или нет? (по умолчанию не сдан)", verbose_name="Готовность объекта")
    ds_contract = models.FileField(default="", upload_to ='project_docs/%Y/%m/%d/', help_text="Загрузите файл", verbose_name="Договор участия в долевом строительстве", blank=True)
    project_dec = models.FileField(default="", upload_to ='project_docs/%Y/%m/%d/', help_text="Загрузите файл", verbose_name="Форма проектной декларации", blank=True)
    ...
    gen_plan = models.FileField(default="", upload_to ='project_docs/%Y/%m/%d/', help_text="Загрузите файл", verbose_name="Генеральный план", blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Проект"
        verbose_name_plural = "Проекты"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Project

def get_project(request, slug):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/project.html', {"projects": projects})
```

Дело в том, что не всегда будут использованы все 14 полей FileField. Как сделать так, чтобы вывести в шаблон только те поля FileFiled, через которые были переданы файлы? А те поля, что не были использованы, не выводить в шаблоне. Второй вопрос. Как для upload_to генерировать папку исходя из переданного значения для поля location?
Заранее благодарю!

Update:

Добавляю template ():

```
{% block content %}
<h2>Тут будет новый строящийся объект</h2>

{% for project in projects %}
    {% for file in project.get_file_fields %}
        {% if file.field %}
           {{ file.label }}: <a href="../../media/{{ file.field }}" target="_blank">Скачать</a><br>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}    
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
def get_project(request, slug):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/project.html', {"projects": projects})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. что бы вывести только те поля FileField, в которых есть значения
   можно добавить в модель следующий метод, который будет выдавать список полей с названиями

```
    def get_file_fields(self):
        return [{"label": field.verbose_name, "field": getattr(self, field.name)} for field in self._meta.get_fields()
                if isinstance(field, models.FileField)]
```

и затем в шаблоне проверять есть ли значение в этом поле, и если есть, выводить его

```
    {% for file in obj.get_file_fields %}
        {% if file.field %}
           {{ file.label }}: {{ file.field}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

где `obj` это экземпляр модели

2. что бы путь зависел от значения другого поля

```
def get_upload_dir(instance, file_name):
    return "{}/{}".format(slugify(instance.location), file_name)


class Project(models.Model):
...
    ds_contract = models.FileField(default="", upload_to=get_upload_dir, help_text="Загрузите файл", verbose_name="Договор участия в долевом строительстве", blank=True)
...
```

вместо `slugify(instance.location)` укажи собственное правило, которое в зависимости от location возвращает нужную папку

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Андрей. По первому вопросу. Все работает. За исключением одного: в целях тестирования я создал два экземпляра класса Project. В первом экземпляре я заполнил несколько FileField и добавил файлы. В другом же экземпляре я не заполнял FileField вообще. И теперь, если я прохожу по ссылке на экземпляр без заполненных FileField полей, то я вижу все файлы с другого экземпляра, где я заполнял FileField. По второму вопросу: (slugify(instance.location) ведь с этим правилом уже должно работать и генерировать папку для сохранения по location, разве нет? Высоко ценю вашу помощь!

Comment: со slugify должно все работать, только нужно не забыть его добавить в import. По поводу файлов, добавь в вопросе template(часть где ты выводишь информацию о файлах), и view в котором ты передаешь контекст

Comment: Добавил. Заранее благодарю!

Comment: мне кажется проблема в том, что у тебя стоит default="", убери default и добавь к свойствам null=True(и пересохранить объекты скорее всего надо будет). А показываются все файлы, потому что у тебя так настроена папка в которой хранится media файлы. По ссылке(по умолчанию у тебя стоит пустая строка) открывается именно папка с media

Comment: убрал default и поставил null=True. Но, к сожалению, все также. Даже после перезаписи экземпляров, они все равно выводят общие файлы. Немного не понял по этому тексту: "А показываются все файлы, потому что у тебя так настроена папка в которой хранится media файлы. По ссылке(по умолчанию у тебя стоит пустая строка) открывается именно папка с media". Что тут именно нужно поменять? Собираюсь дальше искать решение. Спасибо!